# Shouldn't referencing questions be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

For example: [If the article title ends in closing punctuation, do we still add a period in an APA reference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/186058/59258)

Questions like this really have nothing to do with the English language or its usage. Shouldn't they be considered off topic? From the Writers site's [on-topic page](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it looks like they could be migrated there.

Second, if consensus agrees these are off-topic, would it be helpful to have a specific off-topic close reason?

Comment: See http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4328/8019 (Kit's answer to a related question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. Questions about citations are on-topic on Writers and not really about the English **language.**

Writers.SE even have a tag, [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citations) which supports moving questions there:

> Citations are references to published or unpublished sources other than the work one is currently reading. This tag should be used when asking for proper formatting for citations or information about the ethics of citations.

To answer the second question, it's not possible to have automatic migration (which used to be achieved via a close reason) as it led to too many errors. There is also the minor problem that Writers is still in Beta and no migration path exists to Beta sites by design. Those who can vote to close (3000+ rep) can put an off-topic reason; and anyone can flag for moderator attention and write a suitable reason into the "Other" box.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a migration message, but an off-topic message parallel to the proof reading one. The blatantly off topic message is probably fine, but I thought I'd suggest it anyway.